# Python Image Inpainting Produces Poor Results

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create a python script that removes the watermark from an image. In order to do that, I have decided to use the `cv2.inpaint` method. These are the steps that I follow in order to remove the watermark:

1. Get the image from the user
2. Ask the user to shade on the watermark
3. Create a mask out of the user's shading
4. Inpaint the image with the mask created in order to remove the watermark

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
pt1_x , pt1_y = None , None

def nothing(x):
    pass

def line_drawing(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global pt1_x,pt1_y,drawing

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        pt1_x,pt1_y=x,y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            cv2.line(img,(pt1_x,pt1_y),(x,y),color=(0,0,255),thickness= cv2.getTrackbarPos('Thickness','Damaged Image'))
            cv2.line(mask, (pt1_x, pt1_y), (x, y), color=(255,255,255), thickness=cv2.getTrackbarPos('Thickness', 'Damaged Image'))
            pt1_x,pt1_y=x,y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        cv2.line(img,(pt1_x,pt1_y),(x,y),color=(0,0,255),thickness= cv2.getTrackbarPos('Thickness','Damaged Image'))
        cv2.line(mask, (pt1_x, pt1_y), (x, y), color=(255,255,255), thickness=cv2.getTrackbarPos('Thickness', 'Damaged Image'))

img = cv2.imread('D:\\Watermark.jpg')
ratio = img.shape[1]/img.shape[0]

height = 600
width = height * ratio

img = cv2.resize(img, (int(width),height))

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:-1], dtype = np.uint8)
#mask = cv2.integral(mask)
cv2.namedWindow('Mask')

cv2.namedWindow('Damaged Image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Damaged Image',line_drawing)

cv2.createTrackbar('Thickness','Damaged Image', 10, 50, nothing)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('Damaged Image',img)
    cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

    elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        pass

    elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        restored = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
        cv2.namedWindow('Restored Image')
        cv2.imshow('Restored Image', restored)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the image from which I am trying to remove the watermark:

[image]

This is the mask:

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Why is the output so poor? And what can I do to improve the quality of the output? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a quick test, you could try painting your mask much more carefully - maybe just using Photoshop or GIMP initially to see if that helps.

Comment: Ok...Will try that and get back to you. But to be frank, I haven't even used photshop or gimp until now! But I will try my best to create a proper mask with it. But do you think that the problem is with the mask?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't try and that's why I only put a comment rather than an answer. I would assume that as you give OpenCV more and more *"correct"* pixels and ask it to make fewer and fewer guesses, the better it is likely to do. I may be wrong - I have been before, so that's why I suggested a quick test.

Comment: OpenCV inpainting is generally only useful for scratches. Large patched need other inpainting techniques that use patch matching. OpenCV nor Skimage have that approach.

Comment: Oh...That's so sad to hear. Are there any alternatives to remove such large patches from images?

Comment: Can someone pls tell alternatives here?

Comment: @ArnavMehta you could try deep learning approaches: https://github.com/daa233/generative-inpainting-pytorch